# Gtk VB OLE object

Tags: c, linux, gtk

visual basic ole(Object Linking and Embedding) allows programmer to run external program inside the program. Dose gtk have something like that? which let me run another gtk program like evince, gedit, etc inside main. 
actually I want to draw empty window then open gedit inside my window.

Answer (score 1):

On X11, you can use `GtkPlug` and `GtkSocket` to embed a foreign window inside your application. You will have to establish a protocol for obtaining the XID of the application window, for instance by using DBus.

In practice, though, this behaviour is highly discouraged, as it's not portable.

If you want to view a PDF, you can use Poppler (which is what Evince uses), or you can re-use the Evince UI components, which Evince exposes as a library: https://developer.gnome.org/evince/3.14/

If you want the text editing capabilities of gedit, you can use `GtkSourceView`: https://developer.gnome.org/gtksourceview/3.14/

In general, many GNOME and GTK+ applications are componentized and based on shared libraries that other applications can re-use.